# Setting a variable in before cannot be accessed in a beforeEach after the first test

Tags: cypress

Why don't I have access to `@testVariable` after the first `beforeEach`? I should be able to have access to it for each test in this context.

```js
describe('Testing before and beforeEach issue', () => {
  context('testing before and beforeEach', () => {
    before(() => {
      cy.wrap("TESTING 123").as("testVariable")
    })

    beforeEach(() => {
      // This fails after the first beforeEach call.
      cy.get("@testVariable").then((testVariable) => {
        cy.log(`THIS IS A TEST: ${testVariable}`)
      })
    })

    // This test is reached and passes
    it('Testing the variable one time', () => {
      cy.log("THIS IS LOG 1")
    })

    // This test should also pass but is not reached before
    // an error occurs in beforeEach
    it('Testing the variable a second time', () => {
      cy.log("THIS IS LOG 2")
    })
  })
})
```

Here is the test output:

```
  Testing before and beforeEach issue
    testing before and beforeEach
      ✓ Testing the variable one time
      1) "before each" hook for "Testing the variable a second time"


  1 passing (684ms)
  1 failing

  1) Testing before and beforeEach issue
       testing before and beforeEach
         "before each" hook for "Testing the variable a second time":
     CypressError: `cy.get()` could not find a registered alias for: `@testVariable`.
You have not aliased anything yet.

Because this error occurred during a `before each` hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: `testing before and beforeEach`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by design, part of Cypress approach to minimal cross-test pollution (since `beforeEach()` is part of each test).

[Aliases are reset before each test](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Requests)

> **Note:** all aliases are reset before each test. A common user mistake is to create aliases using the before hook. Such aliases work in the first test only!

But there's a loophole. The alias sets up a variable of the same name on the Mocha context (`this`) and it's not cleared between tests.

[Sharing Context](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context)

> Under the hood, aliasing basic objects and primitives utilizes Mocha's shared context object: that is, aliases are available as `this.*` (i.e properties of `this`).

It goes on to say

> Additionally these aliases and properties are automatically cleaned up after each test.

but if you run the following, you find that's not true - the alias is removed but not the context property.

```js
describe('Testing before and beforeEach issue', () => {
  context('testing before and beforeEach', () => {
    before(() => {
      cy.wrap("TESTING 123").as("testVariable")
    })

    // beforeEach(function() {
    //   // This fails after the first beforeEach call.
    //   cy.get("@testVariable").then((testVariable) => {
    //     cy.log(`THIS IS A TEST: ${testVariable}`)
    //   })
    // })
    beforeEach(function() {
      cy.log(`THIS IS A TEST: ${this.testVariable}`)  // logged for each test
    })

    // This test is reached and passes
    it('Testing the variable one time', () => {
      cy.log("THIS IS LOG 1")
    })

    // This test should also pass but is not reached before
    // an error occurs in beforeEach
    it('Testing the variable a second time', () => {
      cy.log("THIS IS LOG 2")
    })
  })
})
```